# Friendlist Program Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a friendlist program in Java.
However, I have to concurrently add a user (object) to two array list.

Is there any way to do so?
My current code is as such but it doesn't seem correct.

```
/* Add this particular person (person in the parameter list) to your friendList
     * Add yourself to this particular person's friendList as well
     *
     * If either you or person-to-be-added's friendList is full (already have 5 friends), 
     *          - print "Friends limit reached."
     *          - Both parties will not add each other.
     * NOTE: Your total number of friends cannot exceed 5 (friendsLimit)
     */ 


public void befriend(Person p){
    //Implement your code here..

            for(Person i : friendList) {
                if(!i.equals(p) && friendList.size() < 5) {
                    friendList.add(p);
                }
                else
                   if(!i.equals(p) && friendList.size() >= 5) {
                       System.out.println("Friends limit reached.");
                   }
                   else {
                       System.out.println("Friend already exist in list");
                   }
            }

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because op did not show any effort at all

Comment: Do you want a more convenient way to add person p to your `friendlist`?

Comment: Time to talk to the [ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ... If friend 0=AAA, 1=BBB, what happens when you try to add BBB?

Comment: No... What i was trying to do is - I've person 1 and 2. If person 1 adds 2, 2 will be added into 1 friendlist. Concurrently, 1 will be added into 2's friendlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just curious, is it intentional that you check if the person to add is already present in the friendlist, because it is not mentioned in the method's comment.
Under the assumption that you have access to the other person's friendlist in, in some way, and the befriend method is a method of a Person:

1. You do not have to iterate over all Persons in your friendlist to assure that neither yours or the other person's friendlist is at full capacity. Just check the bounds and if there is not enough room print the message and call `return;` inside the if clause.
2. If the method `befriend()` is of `Person.befriend()` then you just need to add `friendList.add(p)` and `p.getFriendList().add(this)`
3. If you need do make sure you do not add someone twice, then you can check this in a for loop. But because your Person class have an equals() method, and maybe a hashCode(), you could use the Java Collection method `friendList.contains(p)`(in case friendList is of type ArrayList for example). The collection.contains() method "[...] returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).", see [List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

I hope this helps.

Comment: It certainly does, thank you.